# Line between user support and WPSE scope

Tags: discussion, scope

Hey look: another scope question!

Reference:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40389/wordpress-updates-not-working-why

This one, IMHO, looks like a *user support* question; but, part of me thinks it might be straddling the line. Just looking for clarification/confirmation, before going all "scope-nazi". :)

Comment: Could you please elaborate (1) what do you think "user support" is (2) how is it covered by our FAQ currently (3) how and if it should be discussed and clarified in context of FAQ. I feel by you recent questions on meta that you are using letter of FAQ to back up cases that has not been put in FAQ explicitly and should not be treated negatively in line with its current state.

Comment: **1)** User support is *support for **using** WordPress*, as opposed to administrating or developing WordPress. (Perhaps a better-clarifying answer would be *where is the line between administering and using WordPress?*) **2)** Our scope only addresses *use* of WordPress indirectly, by limiting the audience to administrators and developers. **3)** Absolutely it should be clarified in the scope. As for discussion: at the risk of repetition, I'll start a new question to discuss/clarify the scope line for user support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That particular question is definitely a "help me fix my specific site" issue.  I agree with you 100% and left a comment.  If enough people agree, I'll close it as too localized.

Comment: I cast my "close" vote... but will wait a bit to see if anyone else chimes in on this question, before accepting the answer.

Comment: Close voted too.